# LDAP query does not work when device is domain member

Tags: php, ldap

This php code gives error when my device uses it as domain member.

$ldap = @ldap_connect(ldaphost,ldapport);

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(@ldap_bind($ldap,login,password)){

```
$result = ldap_search($this->lcon,'DC=XXXXXXX,DC=CRP','(&(memberOf=CN=XXXXXX,OU=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=CRP)(sAMAccountName='.login.'))')  ;   
    }
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixing it I used LDAP.php from [here](https://github.com/stepansib/ldap)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ldap = @ldap_connect(ldaphost,ldapport);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
if(@ldap_bind($ldap,login,password)){
    $result = ldap_search($this->lcon,'DC=XXXXXXX,DC=CRP','(&(memberOf=CN=XXXXXX,OU=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=CRP)(sAMAccountName='.login.'))');   
}
```

I just changed the surrounding `"` to `'` and removed the inner `"` in the ldap_search-command.

Comment: I'm sorry that I had mistake in my question.I've corrected it.I would like to bring your attention that when my device is not  domain member this php code works perfectly